# Compute matrix of outer operations on pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have a series where index are labels (Strings) and values are vectors.

I would like to make an outer join of the series with itself where the elements are the dot products of the two vectors.

Ie

```
M_ij = sum over k (x_ik*x_jk)
```

where x_i is the i'th element in the series and k is the index of the vector (and is summed over)

I understand I can convert my series explicitly into matrices and do this operation, but I am wondering if there is a "right" way to do it withing pandas using the Series/DataFrame objects. I also like the idea of preserving the labels these vectors have.

Edit:

Example data

```
x= pd.Series({
'label1': [0,1],
'label2': [1,0],
'label3': [1,1]})

M = function_i_want(x)

M = 

1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 2
```

Edit2:

This is the numpy way of doing it

```
np.dot(np.stack(x),np.stack(x).T)
```

But i would prefer for it to be done as series to generate a data frame with proper labels for columns/indecies.

Comment: Can you provide a data sample and expected output? For example, for [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], what is expected?

Comment: Are you looking for `np.outer`?

Comment: I added example of data. It's not quite np.outer since this generates an outer product of two vectors. I want to apply a custom operation (an inner product) to the outer join of two series. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do all vectors have the same dimension? (I hope)

Comment: Yes, they have. I quite literally can do it in numpy using np.dot(np.stack(x),np.stack(x).T). But I want to have a dataframe so I can access things by using labels instead of indecies. Ie i want to write M['label1'] and see the dot products of vector named label1 with all the other vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way of doing it with numpy -

```
y = np.array(x.tolist())
pd.DataFrame(y.dot(y.T), index=x.index, columns=x.index)

        label1  label2  label3
label1       1       0       1
label2       0       1       1
label3       1       1       2
```

---

The pandas way -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x.tolist(), index=x.index)
df.dot(df.T)

        label1  label2  label3
label1       1       0       1
label2       0       1       1
label3       1       1       2
```